# how to distribute load across multiple ingress pods

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

In the cluster, 2 ingress pods are raised, but when the load is applied to the cluster, requests go only through one pod, tell me with what tools you can use to balance the load distribution between the ingress pods

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a load balancer. It is also possible to create one that is only internal of the cluster so that none get created by your cloud provider: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer